# How to move last li to right most side CSS

Tags: html, css

this is my sample html. i want to move last `li <li class="single"><div id="loader">Loading....</div></li>` to right most side.

```
<div id="content">
    <ul class="paginate pag5 clearfix">
        <li class="single">Page 5 of 5 of 50</li>
        <li class="navpage"><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">prev</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">8</a></li>
        <li class="current">9</li>
        <li class="navpage"><a href="">next</a></li>
        <li class="single"><div id="loader">Loading....</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i use this css

```
.paginate > li:last-child
{
    float:right;
    position:absolute
}
```

but still no luck. see my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/rok4vsaf/

where i made the mistake for which last li is not moving properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remember if you have an absolute element, u cant float it, try this:

```
    .paginate{
       position:relative;
   }
    .paginate > li:last-child
    {
    right:0;
    position:absolute
   }
```

remember to declare the position , in this case "right:0;"

but you can do more simple is , declare the elements like this:

```
.paginate > li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
 }

.paginate >li:last-child{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: i want push the last li at the end of black color.

Comment: can u give jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the trick:

**HTML**

Give the loader `li` a unique class:

```
<li class="single loader"><div id="loader">Loading....</div></li>
                  ^^^^^^
```

**CSS**

Define that class as such:

```
.loader{
  position: relative!important;
  float: right!important;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rok4vsaf/6/)**

Comment: i want push the last li at the end of black color.

Comment: @Mou I updated the fiddle and my response - how about now?

Answer (score 1):

That's all you need:

```css
.paginate > li:last-child
{
    float:right !important;
}
```

---

Remove `position:absolute` from the rule (`.paginate > li:last-child`):

https://jsfiddle.net/rok4vsaf/2/

You don't need to change `position` for this

---

You also need to add `float:right !important;`:

https://jsfiddle.net/rok4vsaf/4/

(otherwise its overwritten with `float: left` in a later rule in your stylesheet, you can prevent this with `!important`)

Comment: what kind of change u did?

Comment: I added the information to my answer. Is that OK for you?

Comment: i want push the last li at the end of black color.

Comment: Ah ok, here you are! Please accept my answer if it works for you

Comment: @mou `float:right !important;` is all you really need ;) anything else is overly complicated

Answer (score 0):

I used it like that which is neater:

```
.paginate > li:last-child
{
    margin-left: auto
    position:absolute
}
```